# I'm curious about the method of fire base security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my firebase rule.

```json
{
  "rules":{
    "users":{
        ".write":"auth.provider == 'anonymous' || auth.token.email.endsWith('dev@email.com')",
        ".read":"auth.token.email.endsWith('dev@email.com')"
    }
  }
}
```

It says unsafe rules.

I wonder why, and there's no way to know how to improve it Help me

Comment: Those rules should not be flagged as unsafe by Firebase. Are you sure it's been at least 24 hours since you saved/deployed them? If so, can you copy/paste the text of the email your received into your question?

Comment: sorry but Even after 3 days of registration, you will receive mail continuously.

Comment: OK, so can you copy/paste the text of the email you received into your question?

Comment: The following issues have been detected in the security rule:

All users can read the entire database.
All users can write to the entire database.

Comment: I don't think there will be any more emails My rule is different from the one I was guided to.